# Same prefab instantiates at different speed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to set up an object to instantiate bullets 4 ways when firing. For example as following:

```
Assuming 'A' is the object:

    ^
    |
<-  A  ->
    |
    v
```

I am trying to set it up to shoot 4 ways in the directions specified above. The current setup works and the prefabs instantiate correctly in the directions. Problem is not all shoots out at the same speed. The right and bottom one shoots out correctly while the top and left ones shoots out way slower.

The code setup is exactly the same for all directions and all of them are using the same prefab and same speed thus confused as to why the difference in speed. Please advice. Thanks.

[Dropbox link to project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/0ys0o0zl0r7haf3/AACAlv0AEHb7ufpcKbLQl9tHa?dl=0)

```
    public Rigidbody bulletPrefab;
    //empty gameobjects to locate the positions
    public Transform bulletStartPosRight, bulletStartPosLeft, bulletStartPosTop, bulletStartPosBottom;
    private float bulletSpeed = 300;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Rigidbody bulletInstance1, bulletInstance2, bulletInstance3, bulletInstance4;  

            bulletInstance1 = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletStartPosRight.position, bulletStartPosRight.rotation) as Rigidbody;
            //the force is always forward. I rotated the empty gameobjects in Unity instead of changing the code here to forward,up,right and so on. 
            bulletInstance1.AddForce(bulletStartPosRight.forward * bulletSpeed);

            bulletInstance2 = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletStartPosLeft.position, bulletStartPosLeft.rotation) as Rigidbody;
            bulletInstance2.AddForce(bulletStartPosLeft.forward * bulletSpeed);

            bulletInstance3 = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletStartPosTop.position, bulletStartPosTop.rotation) as Rigidbody;
            bulletInstance3.AddForce(bulletStartPosTop.forward * bulletSpeed);

            bulletInstance4 = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, bulletStartPosBottom.position, bulletStartPosBottom.rotation) as Rigidbody;
            bulletInstance4.AddForce(bulletStartPosBottom.forward * bulletSpeed);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Rather than calling `AddForce`, you might try assigning the new rigidbody's `velocity` property directly. This avoids any circumstance where pre-existing velocity might affect the bullet. Aside from that, you should double check that all of your rotations are exactly what you expect.

Comment: The rotation is correct and the velocity is still giving same results. Extracted this portion of the problem and created a small Unity project file. Do take a look if you have time. The dropbox link is in the question above. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the project and noticed that the top & left spawnpoints were rotated the wrong way.

- The left rotation should be: 270 (or -90)
- The top rotation should be: 180

Personally I'd lose all of the rotations and use transform.right etc. to avoid confusion

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I opted to make it all forward cos there is no option to code it as left, down. There is only forward, up, right. Do advice if there is a way to obtain left and bottom.

Comment: You can simply use left and down by doing: -transform.right and -transform.up

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you are using AddForce in the update method. You should try using the FixedUpdate method instead.  It states in the online documentation at:

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html

In a script, the FixedUpdate function is recommended as the place to apply forces and change Rigidbody settings (as opposed to Update, which is used for most other frame update tasks). The reason for this is that physics updates are carried out in measured time steps that don't coincide with the frame update. FixedUpdate is called immediately before each physics update and so any changes made there will be processed directly.